# thunderbird - how to have emails erased automatically removed from gmail?

Tags: gmail, thunderbird, imap

I understand that by connecting via imap to my gmail account with thunderbird, whatever i do in thunderbird would be reflected in gmail.

Yet, if i delete emails in thunderbird, those emails are still present in gmail, even after a while. I set my account preferences in thunderbird under the option "leave messages on the server?" to: "until i delete them".

Did i understood imap wrong, or did i set up something wrong? I would really like to be able to clean up my gmail account via a desktop client, such as thunderbird, as it is much more responsive, and i have 4gb of messages to clean up.

Answer (score 0):

There's a weird interplay between Tbird and Gmail with labels.  If any of those messages have additional labels on them, they will persist in Gmail unless you remove those labels.

[There's some more info here](http://www.techlifeweb.com/2007/10/27/gmail-imap-and-thunderbird/), check the bottom for details on what functions in Tbird do in Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake: in fact i thought i was connecting via imap, but i wasn't. Make sure it says "IMAP server" under "Server settings > Server type".